# Php system that perform specific task based on time

Tags: php

I want to develop a system that perform specific task based on time however,  if i use php time function  for example if some 1 change the server time  it affect my program any solution to avoid using server time?

Comment: php uses the servers time, so yes.

Comment: what do you mean "if someone changes the server time?" like an intruder?

Comment: Look for php [cron jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

Comment: Yes an intruder

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use a [NTP server](http://www.kloth.net/software/timesrv1.php) so your system won't depend on the server time but on a remote server.

There is an working code example in this answer: [Retrieve Time from NTP server via PHP - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592142/retrieve-time-from-ntp-server-via-php?answertab=active#tab-top).